# Grouping by key according to minimum order value

Tags: sql-server

I am using **SQL Server**.

I have a table like this:

| Key | Rule_Name | Rule_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | VAT | 15 |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | VAT | 15 |
| Key1 | VAT | 15 |

and I am looking for this:

| Key | Rule_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Key1 | interco |

In other words, I need to group by the key and get the rule name that matches the smallest value of the **Rule_Order**.

At first, I was thinking about this:

```
select [Key], [Rule_Name]
from (
  select [Key],
    min([Rule_Order]),
    min([Rule_Name])
  from 
    mytable
  group by [Key]
)
```

which works with the example above, however the min([Rule_Name]) will look for the **Rule_Name** that comes first in alphabetic order.

If I change the rule order like this:

| Key | Rule_Name | Rule_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | VAT | 10 |
| Key1 | interco | 12 |
| Key1 | VAT | 10 |
| Key1 | VAT | 10 |

then the query above will give me this:

| Key | Rule_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Key1 | interco |

which is not what I want, as VAT is associated to the smallest rule order.

I understand that the word 'interco' comes before 'VAT' in the alphabet.
I naively thought that order of the aggregators would be important in the group by:
listing first rules of smallest order with min([Rule_Order]) THEN retrieving the rule names associated with this order. In my case, because there is alway one rule associated with a given order, I thought that using min or max would not be important. But it turned to be wrong.

So how should the query look like in that case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use use PARTITION or ROW_NUMBER() ? Is this an assignment ?

Comment: Forget about this, I edited my question. In fact, I am using Power Query, and I need the query to fold back into my SQL Server. Using PARTITION or ROW_NUMBER() does not work out of the box, unless I create a native query. Since I can do that, I edited my question. I believe that I only have 2 options: using window, or subquery.

Comment: Yeap. Using ROW_NUMBER is how I would solve this. What doesn't work with that?

Comment: @SeanLange, like I said, I was thinking of Power Query transformations that would _fold_ to the backend, and windows are not (yet) supported **unless** you create native queries. I just needed to think outside of the box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use row_number in a sub-query or a cte.

> ```
> create table t(
> Key_ varchar(10),
> Rule_Name varchar(10),
> Rule_Order int);
> insert into t values
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','VAT',10),
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','VAT',10),
> ('Key1','VAT',15),
> ('Key2','test',5);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   key_,
>   rule_name
> from 
> (select
>   key_,
>   rule_name,
>   row_number() over 
>       (partition by key_
>       order by rule_order) rn
> from t) as sq
> where rn = 1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> key_ | rule_name
> :--- | :--------
> Key1 | VAT      
> Key2 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff7918a5c00e80bc499d1c0d9275831d)*

Answer (score 0):

The function `FIRST_VALUE` does exactly what we are looking for.

> ```
> create table t(
> Key_ varchar(10),
> Rule_Name varchar(10),
> Rule_Order int);
> insert into t values
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','VAT',10),
> ('Key1','interco',12),
> ('Key1','VAT',10),
> ('Key1','VAT',15),
> ('Key2','test',5);
> ```

> ```
> select distinct
>   key_,
>   first_value(rule_name) over
>       (partition by key_ 
>        order by rule_order)
>       as rule_name
> from t;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> key_ | rule_name
> :--- | :--------
> Key1 | VAT      
> Key2 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e89035f5e85c145ed609f130d4ba02ff)*

Comment: I was able to check your suggested SQL statement, and I confirm it works for me too. However, this does not support _query folding_ when used in Power Query transformations, so your first answer is the perfect fit for my use case (not sure if this is the _first_value_ or _distinct_ statement that breaks it). Since it may help others, I thought I'd comment. Again, thank you!